# convert one date format into another date format does not work c++

Tags: c++, datetime, time, datetime-format

Hello I want to convert this dateformat

2022-11-17T112139.568+0100

into this dateformat

2022-11-17 11:21:39

This is my code

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    std::string testString = "2022-11-17T112139.568+0100";
    struct tm source ;
    strptime(testString.c_str(), "%y-%M-%dT%H%m%s.%S%Z", &source);
    std::cout << "Second: " << source.tm_sec << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Minute: " << source.tm_min << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hour: " << source.tm_hour << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Day: " << source.tm_mday << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Month: " << source.tm_mon <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "Year: " << source.tm_year << std::endl;
    char dest[20];
    strftime(dest, sizeof(dest), "%y-%M-%d %H:%m:%s", &source);
    std::cout << "Output: " << dest << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
Second: 1
Minute: 0
Hour: -421736992
Day: 32767
Month: 6299080
Year: 120
Output: 20-00-32767
```

How can I convert one dateformat into another date format in c++?
i also tried the boost library but that did not work either

Comment: 'M' is the minute, 'm' is the month and others...https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html

Comment: Start with reading the manual. **%y**     The year within century (0–99). You give 2022. And many other date fields are wrong. Check the returned value.

Comment: An alternative to `strptime` and `strftime` is the [`<chrono>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/chrono) date-and-time library portion of the standard C++ library.

Comment: @Eljay yes I posted my solution. Maybe there is a more c++ like solution but for now it works

Answer (score 1):

Indeed I had a wrong source for formating string.
This works now:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    std::string testString = "2022-11-17T112139.568+0100";
    struct tm source ;
    strptime(testString.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S.%FFF%Z", &source);
    std::cout << "Second: " << source.tm_sec << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Minute: " << source.tm_min << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Hour: " << source.tm_hour << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Day: " << source.tm_mday << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Month: " << source.tm_mon <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "Year: " << source.tm_year << std::endl;
    char dest[20];
    strftime(dest, sizeof(dest), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &source);
    std::cout << "Output: " << dest << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe somebody has a good cheat sheet for formating dates? For example the Milliseconds one I was only able to find out by testing and googling